# What are the methods to paginate a table 100 rows at a time?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, pagination

Let's say we have a table with a large number of records. Now to show all the data using pagination in a basic framework using a MySQL query, we can use limits to get a subset of rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION ORDER BY COLUMN1 LIMIT 0,100;
```

and so on.

To my understanding, `LIMIT` will work once the temporary result table is generated, or in other words, the search will go through all the rows once and then the final result will be populated. Am I right?

The query result takes much time to get data with `limit` and sometimes the system just reaches execution time limits. Is there any other better solution for this?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense. Anycase server must count records one-by-one until OFFSET then count and return LIMIT records (so LIMIT 0,100 is much faster then LIMIT 100000,100) then stop counting, but it is easier (and more fast) when the index applicable for specified ORDER BY expression exists.

Comment: *Is there any best solution?* There is not "best solution" for to select and paginate the **whole** huge table, especially without ordering. The only optimization is pre-pagination (pre-calculate and use PageNumber-IDsRange).

Comment: @Akina I've edited my question by adding `ORDER BY` and also checked for the result with your stated clause but still, my site takes too much time to retrieve results and sometimes reach execution limit.

Comment: @James Isn't it that `WHERE` clause will make to retrieve all the result once and then `LIMIT` will be applied to the resultant temporary data?

Comment: One page = 100 records, is it? How many records are selected by the query without LIMIT?

Comment: @Akina The table contains 45K rows in total for now

Comment: I.e. 450 pages max? And what is MySQL version?

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: @Akina The records to display in each page is dynamic, it can be selected anywhere between 10 to 200. The current version being used is 5.7

Comment: When the first access to the table (get 1st page with specified conditions and ordering) occured perform quick enumeration for all query result storing IDs and according positions into temporary table. Then simply use this table to select records for page N by calculated position between ((N-1)*countperpage+1) and (N*countperpage). Exclusion - the tail (with posssible new records) - query it directly using backward ordering. Of course everything must be performed in the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for pagination is not to use `OFFSET`.  Instead "remember where you left off".  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

However, there are cases where that is difficult.  In your example of

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE CONDITION                -- This
    ORDER BY COLUMN1 LIMIT 0,100;
```

This works nicely.  The 1st page will take only as long as fetching the 100 rows for it.  And the 1000th page will be delivered as fast as the 1st.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE id > $left_off            -- where you left off
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 100;
```

But if the 'condition' is too messy, it may have to gather all the rows, and only then figure out where you left off.  `JOINs` often add to the messiness.

If you would like to give the specific query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we can discuss *your* situation.

> LIMIT will work once the temporary result table is formulated

It depends on whether a single (possibly 'composite') index can short circuit things.

What you really need to worry about is "`OFFSET` must step over the skipped rows."  That's why "left off" may work much better.